# How to implement a Spamword filter in php contact form and reCaptcha

Tags: php, filter, contacts, captcha, spam

I 've a contact form with a working reCaptcha on it, but some spam gets through.
I've tried adding a spamword filter I've found in here  [Spam Filter in Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185920/spam-filter-in-contact-form)
. But it doesn't work, any ideas?

EDIT: ( further explanation, noob mistake) The filter scans through the words in the message field and blocks the mail sending If a word is present.

Nowadays I almost have no spam thanks to recaptcha, but there's like 10 mails a 
day advertising Prednisone or Viagra. so, Id like to filter those words ir order to avoid receiving that spam

I've tried inserting the solution I've mentioned before but I receive those mails anyways

Here's my code
I've tried  putting the code from the previous post in several different places with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php
    // require ReCaptcha class
    require '../recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php';
    //require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/recaptcha-master/src/autoload.php');

    // configure
    // an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
    $from = 'Formulario de contacto <blehblehbleh@somethingsomething.com>';

    // an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
    $sendTo = 'InfoPapelCosido <blablabla@somethingsomething.com>';

    // subject of the email
    $subject = 'Mensaje Nuevo desde la web de PapelCosido';

    // form field names and their translations.
    // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
    $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');

    // message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
    $okMessage = 'Mensaje enviado, a la brevedad nos comunicaremos con usted.';

    // If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
    $errorMessage = 'Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje, por favor intente mas tarde';

    // ReCaptch Secret
    $recaptchaSecret = '#######################';

    // let's do the sending
    // if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    try {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception,

            // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block
            if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
                throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
            }
            // do not forget to enter your secret key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin
            $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

            // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address
            $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

            if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
                throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
            }


            // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually
            $emailText = "Mensaje desde la web\n=============================\n";

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
                if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                    $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
                }
            }

            // All the neccessary headers for the email.
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
                'From: ' . $from,
                'Reply-To: ' . $from,
                'Return-Path: ' . $from,
            );


    // THIS IS THE CODE FROM THE POST I'VE CITED BEFORE
//TEST SPAM FILTER
            // Prevent spammers from using contact form
                //Create an array containing the words in the message
                $MessageArray = explode(" ", $emailText   );
                //Get SPAM words from file and store them in an array
                $SpamWords = file_get_contents('spamwords.txt');
                $SpamArray = explode("\r\n", $SpamWords);
                //Cycle through all the words in the message
                foreach($MessageArray as $word){
                    //Check the word for SPAM words, if it is don't send the email
                    if(in_array($word, $SpamArray)){
                        echo '<h1>Spam Guard</h1>';
                        echo '<p>Here in European Community, the <a href="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/2426/pdfs/uksi_20032426_en.pdf">Privacy and Electronic Communications Regulations 2003</a> cover the sending of email marketing. This legislation says that organisations must only send marketing emails to anyone if they have agreed to receive them, except where there is a clearly defined customer relationship.</p>';
                        echo '<p>It appears that you are attempting to send an unsolicited message (e.g. a marketing message).</p>';
                        echo '<p>We as an organisation do not send unsolicited messages and we request that you do the same for us.</p>';
                        echo '<p>If you are not attempting to send an unsolicited message, there may be an error in the system so please accept our apologies.</p>';
                        die();
                    }
                }
                //If we've made it to this point, our message doesn't contain any obvious SPAM words
    //END SPAM FILTER



            // Send email
            mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

            $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
            }

            } 

            catch (\Exception $e) {
            $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
            }

            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo $encoded;
            } else {
            echo $responseArray['message'];
            }
```

Comment: `but some spam gets through` what type of spam?

Comment: What exactly means "it doesn't work" What happens and what would you want to happen. It would also help to describe what is important about the web page, e.g. which field or which variable contains the data you want to check for possible spam...

Comment: Sorry guys, noob error, the filter scans through the words in the message field and blocks the mail sending If a word is present.

Nowadays I almost have no spam thanks to recaptcha, but there's like 10 mails a 
day advertising Prednisone or Viagra. so, Id like to filter those words ir order to avoid receiving that spam

I've tried inserting the solution I've mentioned before but I receive those mails anyways